# What is the exact size of all the Warhammer 40k bases?

Tags: warhammer-40k, basing

I'm looking for a list of the dimensions of all the bases in Warhammer 40k.

I know there is a 60mm base, for large models, and there is one that is 120mm x 55mm for really large models.

I don't know the sizes for the smaller models, or for the flying models.

I feel like a list of all the sizes would be very handy, but I can't find all of them in one place.  A list of all the square bases from Warhammer Fantasy would be useful too.  I don't own many of those models, so I have nothing to measure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are the supported base sizes in 40K

- Standard Infantry - 25mm round
- Large Infantry - 40mm round
- Monsters - 60mm round
- Flyer - 90x120mm oval
- Bike Bases - 25x70mm oval
- Clear flight stands small - 30mm round
- Clear flight stands large - 60mm round

For Fantasy:

- Standard Infantry - 20mm square
- Large Infantry - 25mm square
- Monsters - 40mm square
- Cavalry - 25x50mm rectangle

Comment: Perfect!  That is super helpful!

Comment: Note that this is now *very* out of date. 40K now widely uses the 32mm bases, the bike base has changed, and fantasy has gone to round bases entirely.

Comment: Amusingly, the comment saying this is out of date is now out of date with the rerelease of Fantasy as The Old World... I wait for another comment in 6 years when my comment is out of date because we've gone to hexagonal bases or something.